# Sharepoint 2013 - Get Mysite Document Details Report

Tags: 2013, document-library, sharepoint-list, mysite

I'm quite new to SharePoint and powershell scripting. I need some assistance in getting document details of the below from Mysite.

It currently has several user profiles storing both their Personal and Shared docs. I need to get the below details across both libraries:

- Document names
- Usernames
- Date modified

So far I've tried using the below script which comes close to what I'm looking for, but info is quite limited.

It gets the user's profile URL (so that covers the usernames bit) and the number of documents, but not the other details stated above.

Please help on how I can get the extra info. I suspect I'll have to query more in the 'Select-Object' line, but I'm unsure as to what the keywords might be?

```
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

Start-SPAssignment -Global

$OutputFile = "C:\temp\MysiteDocsProd.csv"

$results = @()


$webApps = Get-SPWebApplication https://mysite.sharepoint.com
foreach($webApp in $webApps)
{
    foreach($siteColl in $webApp.Sites)
    {
        foreach($web in $siteColl.AllWebs)
        {
            $webUrl = $web.url
            $docLibs = $web.Lists | Where-Object {$_.baseType -eq "DocumentLibrary"}
            $docLibs | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name WebUrl -Value {$webUrl}
            $results += ($docLibs | Select-Object -Property WebUrl, Title, ItemCount)
        }
    }
}

$results | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation


Stop-SPAssignment -Global
```

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the all file name details, you need to loop through the items collection object.

Below is the document library inventory function where you just need to pass your mysite URL.

```
    #Original Code provided by Gary Lapoint
    # http://blog.falchionconsulting.com

    [void]   [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“Microsoft.SharePoint”)
    function Get-DocumentLibraryInventory([string]$siteUrl) {
     $site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite $siteUrl
    foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) {
    foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {
    if ($list.BaseType -ne “DocumentLibrary”) {
       continue
      }
    foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
    $data = @{
     “Site” = $site.Url
     “Web” = $web.Url
     “list” = $list.Title
      “Item ID” = $item.ID
      “Item URL” = $item.Url
       “Item Title” = $item.Title
       “Item Created” = $item[“Created”]
        “Item Modified” = $item[“Modified”]
       “File Size” = $item.File.Length/1KB
     }
        New-Object PSObject -Property     $data
    }
             }
              $web.Dispose();
                }
                $site.Dispose()
                }
                 $sitecollection = read-host     “Enter Site Collection Url”

#Get- DocumentLibraryInventory    “http://sp2007” | Out-GridView
Get-DocumentLibraryInventory $sitecollection  | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path Report_SC_Docs.csv
```

Reference URL :

[GET A LIST OF ALL DOCUMENTS AND ITEMS IN DOCUMENT LIBRARIES WITH POWERSHELL](http://techrevmarrell.com/2012/05/23/get-a-list-of-all-documents-and-items-in-document-libraries-with-powershell/)

Comment: Thanks for that SP Expert. I tried the above and it gave me URL details of pages within the site. It didnt bring up details of the subsites created for each user profile. Apologies if i wasn't clear to begin with.